# How to assign result of OUTPUT DELETED to an output parameter?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, output-parameter

I have the following query that generates the next available bill of lading numbers.

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetNextTruckBol]
    @FacilityId INT,
    @Count INT = 1
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    UPDATE Facilities
    SET NextTruckBol = NextTruckBol + @Count
    OUTPUT DELETED.NextTruckBol
    WHERE Id = @FacilityId
END
```

But now I need to modify it so that the resulting value is instead assigned to an `OUTPUT` parameter.

I know how to declare the `OUTPUT` parameter. How can I assign the value of `OUTPUT DELETED.NextTruckBol` to that parameter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per the [`UPDATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) documentation

> Variable names can be used in UPDATE statements to show the old and
> new values affected, but this should be used only when the UPDATE
> statement affects a single record. If the UPDATE statement affects
> multiple records, to return the old and new values for each record,
> use the OUTPUT clause.

So if you know that the `UPDATE` will only affect max one row (as `Id` is constrained to be unique) and you don't want to mess around with table variables you can use

> `SET @variable = column, column = expression`, which sets the variable
> to the pre-update value of the column.

So that would be

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetNextTruckBol]
    @FacilityId INT,
    @Count INT = 1,
    @NextTruckBol INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE Facilities
    SET @NextTruckBol = NextTruckBol,
        NextTruckBol = NextTruckBol + @Count
    WHERE Id = @FacilityId
END
```

Comment: Woah! Didn't know you could do that. Thanks. One major concern is that this operation needs to block so that another process couldn't get the same number before I finish. Do you know if your example would maintain that lock?

Comment: yes. It will happen whilst the row is locked

Comment: Both update operation and set a variable? That goes to favorites!